# Docker file error: failed to read dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I made sure that the Dockerfile is named correctly and placed in the right folder, but when I try to build an image it is throwing me to an error "ERROR: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount636325941/Dockerfile: no such file or directory". Here is my Dockerfile content, I have both the requirements.txt and training_model.py in the same src folder. :

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.10

# Set environment variables for AWS credentials (replace with your credentials)
ENV MINIO_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your_access_key
ENV MINIO_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=your_secret_key
ENV MINIO_ENDPOINT=your_minio_endpoint
ENV MINIO_BUCKET_NAME=your_bucket_name

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the requirements file into the container
COPY requirements.txt .

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the rest of the application code into the container
COPY . .

# Command to run the training and model publishing script
CMD ["python", "training_model.py"]
```

Here is the ls and dir:

```
PS C:\Users\mrsta\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\ML\src> ls


    Directory: C:\Users\mrsta\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\ML\src


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         12/9/2023   3:19 PM            704 Dockerfile.txt
-a----         12/9/2023   3:11 PM             61 requirements.txt
-a----         12/9/2023   3:55 PM           3736 training_model.py


PS C:\Users\mrsta\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\ML\src> dir


    Directory: C:\Users\mrsta\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\ML\src


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         12/9/2023   3:19 PM            704 Dockerfile.txt
-a----         12/9/2023   3:11 PM             61 requirements.txt
-a----         12/9/2023   3:55 PM           3736 training_model.py
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Include the output of `ls` or `dir` showing the directory contents. Please do not use screenshots of text, post the formatted text.

Comment: I included that. I will leave my screenshots here as well just so if anyone wanna look at.

Comment: It's recommended to configure your explorer window to show file extensions, we can see that the file name is actually `Dockerfile.txt` and not `Dockerfile` in the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Your Dockerfile is named `Dockerfile.txt`. The file should just be `Dockerfile` with no extension. Most likely your IDE or file manager is hiding extensions from you, so you'll need to turn off that option or pick a different way to name the file.

From a Linux CLI, renaming the file would be `mv Dockerfile.txt Dockerfile`. That would also work with Git bash.

Comment: If you do need a different name to your dockerfile, you can pass the `-f` parameter to `docker build`. I will not recommend anyone to name their file `Dockerfile.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

If the `Dockerfile` is in the working directory of your shell then no need to pass the file as an argument since the `docker build` command will automatically look  for a file named `Dockerfile` in the current working directory.

Same thing with the context directory, you could simply replace it with `.` rather that `C:\Users\..`.

Therefore a shorter command would look like `docker build -t model-training-image:1.0 .` (don't forget the dot at the end).

Try using the above command first. If it still doesn't work, then there is indeed a typo in your file, or it doesn't exist in the current working directory.

EDIT : Just saw that you added screenshots of `ls`. You have the `.txt` extension. Remove it

Comment: I actually did that docker build -t model-training-image:1.0 . , but it doesn't work, hence I specify the path. Do you mean there is a typo in my Dockerfile? I also did ls command and it does show all the files when I am in the path.

Comment: Check that the Dockerfile is named "Dockerfile". 10 letters, capital D, no other capital letters. Then try running the `docker build` command with the option `-f`, but let the shell auto-completion build the name of the file.

Comment: It is Dockerfile. I tried hitting docker build -f + TAB, it linked directly to my path "C:\Users\mrsta\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\ML\src\Dockerfile.txt" but throw an error because I didn't use -t i assume. 
ERROR: "docker buildx build" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker buildx build --help'.", and also to clarify the .txt is not in my filename, so only 'Dockerfile'.

Comment: Is is because I run it in VS Code terminal? I assume that's not a problem right? I was following a YT video tutorial and he's doing the same and it works.

Comment: Why does it have the `.txt` extension ? Remove it, the filename should just be `Dockerfile` without the ``.txt` extension